# Unable to fetch all objects in IE 11 using UFT 12.54

Tags: internet-explorer, automation, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

*I have IE 8 before and able to fetch all the object using object respositary by single click on top of the browser.

*Then clicked on title bar of browser.

*Then GMail objects are in object repositary and the objects are [all the objects of gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apWnf.png)

*Due to some version issue i have updated to IE 11. From that unable to fetch all the objects in web browser by clicking on top of the browser.

It shows as "WinObject : Client Caption".
Please help me on this.[final object shows as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc5p8.png)

Comment: Default question: What add-ons you have enabled in UFT? Have you opened UFT *before* opening the browser?

Comment: Activex, Visual Basic, Web, WPF

Comment: You didn't answer my second question so I'll ask again: did you open UFT *before* opening the browser? Now a new question: have you seen [vins answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41727696/6352151)?

Comment: Sorry @VictorMoraes , I opened browser after opening UFT. And I already tried vins answer also. still not able to find object.. Am able to fetch particular field object in browser.. my only concern is all about to fetch all the objects which is present in browser by tapping on top of the browser.

Comment: I have tried all the above and Bhomanager.dll is already enabled and same issue still persisting.. Further, can u please tell me the same thing how can i do for chrome..? in Chrome if i detect object on top of browser it shows me as **Window : Google chrome** and there is no drop down list which have objects in that.. Further if i select any field it detects as **Chrome legacy window**. Bcoz of this am unable to write code. Do i have install any patch file ? if anything please tell me that also...

Comment: You said you already tried vins answer and also said: *"Am able to fetch particular field object in browser.. my only concern is all about to fetch all the objects which is present in browser by tapping on top of the browser."*. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41718961/edit) your question and describe **everything** you have already tried to identify your objects. Also describe **exactly** what are the steps you are performing in order to try to identify all objects at once. This will make it easier for us to assist you and give you focused answers

Answer (score 1):

1) There is a chance that `bhomanager.dll` is not enabled for IE11.

IE11 Settings -> Manage Add-ons-> enable BHOManager.dll

2) web addin should have been enabled for UFT

3) Browser should be launched after launching UFT.

---

Mostly above are the solutions for this sort of issues. If it is not resolved, then It could be particular combo issue.

If you have Windows 10 + UFT 12.54 + IE11 combo, then probably check this.

http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.54/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/Edge_Extension_Setup.htm

Check IE11 has some kind of compatibility mode selected to edge..etc

Comment: I have tried all the above and Bhomanager.dll is already enabled and same issue still persisting.. Further, can u please tell me the same thing how can i do for chrome..? in Chrome if i detect object on top of browser it shows me as **Window : Google chrome** and there is no drop down list which have objects in that.. Further if i select any field it detects as **Chrome legacy window**. Bcoz of this am unable to write code. Do i have install any patch file ? if anything please tell me that also...

Comment: Chrome does not work with UFT out of the box. you need to have batches installed/enabled.

Comment: by any chance you have win 10?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added your URL to your Trusted sites and that you have "Enable Protected Mode" unchecked.

[image]